# Can I import the data exported from the relational database into the Apache IoTDB?

Tags: apache-iotdb, iotdb

**Can I import the data exported from the relational database into the Apache IoTDB?**

**I just came across iotdb, I've been using a relational database before, and now I want to switch to iotdb.So know I need to import the data from the relational database I used before,can I achieve this?**

If it can , what should I do?

Thank you very much.